# How to proof recursively defined functions' prop in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove a lemma called alignof_correct in Coq, which verifies that the alignof function I defined for a type returns a positive value. I have defined the types and the function, and imported the ZArith library.

```
Require Import ZArith.

Inductive type :=
| Tstruct : nat -> fieldlist -> type
with fieldlist :=
| Fnil : fieldlist
| Fcons : nat -> type -> fieldlist -> fieldlist.

Fixpoint alignof (ty: type): Z :=
  match ty with
  | Tstruct _ fld => alignof_fields fld
  end
with alignof_fields (fld: fieldlist): Z :=
  match fld with
  | Fnil => 1
  | Fcons _ ty fld' => Z.max (alignof ty) (alignof_fields fld')
  end.

Lemma alignof_correct : forall (ty : type),
  (alignof ty > 0)%Z.
Proof.
  intros ty. induction ty.
  simpl. apply Z.gt_lt_iff. 
  admit.
Admitted.
```

Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to prove these? Thank you!!

Comment: I recommend, for the sake of the question, deleting all constructors of `type` except `Tstruct`, to make the salient points of the example easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to prove mutual lemmas:

```
Lemma alignof_correct : forall (ty : type),
  (alignof ty > 0)%Z
with alignof_fields_correct: forall (fld: fieldlist),
    (alignof_fields fld > 0)%Z.
Proof.
  - intros ty. induction ty;try now reflexivity.
    + simpl. apply IHty.
    + simpl. 
      apply alignof_fields_correct.
  - induction fld.
    + simpl. auto with zarith.
    + simpl.
      auto with zarith.
Qed.
```

That said the second proof does not make use of the mutual induction hypothesis so in this particular case you can prove the `field` stuff alone first:

```
Lemma alignof_fields_correct: forall (fld: fieldlist),
    (alignof_fields fld > 0)%Z.
Proof.
  induction fld.
    + simpl. auto with zarith.
    + simpl.
      auto with zarith.
Qed.

Lemma alignof_correct : forall (ty : type),
  (alignof ty > 0)%Z.
Proof.
  intros ty.
  induction ty;try now reflexivity.
  + simpl. apply IHty.
  + simpl. 
    apply alignof_fields_correct.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, it has been a great help to me! Now I understand, thanks.

Comment: Ohh, I still have a question. If alignof_fields_correct needs alignof_correct to be proven, is it ok to define it in this way?

Comment: If there is a mutual dependency between the two lemmas, then you may have to make one big proof my mutual induction.  I haven't done that in a long time...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple example of mutual induction p. 400 of

https://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Yves.Bertot/coqart-chapter14.pdf

The scripts for recents version of Coq are maintained in

https://github.com/coq-community/coq-art/tree/master/ch14_fundations_of_inductive_types/SRC

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

The initial example provided is to proof that the alignment is positive, Courtieu's answer helped. However I realized that those two theorems that I actually have are mutually dependent. It is necessary to use alignof_correct to prove alignof_fields_correct, This is not a very appropriate example:

```
Inductive alignof_prop: type -> Z -> Prop :=
  | alignof_Tstruct : 
    forall i fld z,
    alignof_fields_prop fld z ->
    alignof_prop (Tstruct i fld) z
with alignof_fields_prop: fieldlist -> Z -> Prop :=
  | alignof_fields_nil : 
    alignof_fields_prop Fnil 1
  | alignof_fields_cons : 
    forall i ty fld z1 z2,
    alignof_prop ty z1 ->
    alignof_fields_prop fld z2 ->
    alignof_fields_prop (Fcons i ty fld) (Z.max z1 z2).
```

So we can get this:

```
Lemma alignof_correct:
  forall ty,
  alignof_prop ty (alignof ty)
  with alignof_fields_correct:
  forall f,
  alignof_fields_prop f (alignof_fields f).
Proof.
  induction ty; simpl; econstructor. auto. apply alignof_fields_correct.
  induction f; simpl; econstructor. apply alignof_correct. auto.
Qed.
```

P.S. Perhaps I'm not quite clear on how 'with' works when describing a theorem. Could anyone please let me know where I can find relevant reference materials?